# Can we do silent updation for android application?

Tags: android, auto-update, android-install-apk, silent-installer

Is there any way to make automatic silent update for corporative app?
We have an app that working only with local network and WEB-service.
Tablets works thru Wi-Fi, but has no access to internet because of
security. We need to get something like this functionality:

1. Administrator put some updates to server.
2. App downloads files and automaticly update itself without any
   additional action of users.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There's currently no public way of doing so.

Answer (score 2):

Such an upgrade without the android market is possible only if the device is rooted, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15085540/516188

Answer (score 0):

It depend on exactly what you are requesting. You can't update with a new apk file but you can download files in the background without the user notices and if you have embedded web interface you can completely change your website which you link/embed in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can background download your application apk file => call installer (use service)
or use C2DM but it **must ask user's permission** to update. All app on google play do it this way. May be you can decompile google play and find some hidden permissions.