# pm command giving Segmentation fault

Tags: java, android, apk

I am trying to update an Apk on Android Remotely. To run the update without the need of user intervention, I am using this post [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982174/self-updating-app/15085540#15085540) .

But the process is returning with the exit code 139 which means Segmentation fault. My tablet is rooted and I have confirmed it.

```
File file = new File(Constants.UPDATE_APK_PATH);
    try {
        String[] filenames = file.list();
        File apk = new File(file, filenames[0]);
        Process pid = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                new String[] { "su", "-c",
                        "pm install -r "+apk.getAbsolutePath()});
        pid.waitFor();
```

Can anybody tell what exactly i am doing wrong? The file is present at the location and the signature of both the apk is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure if you use `adb install` instead of `pm install` would resolve this issue. 
But i believe in this case application does not have enough permissions to install packages.

Comment: How can execute adb from activity?? I have already added these permissions "android.permission.FACTORY_TEST", "android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES", "android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES". Can you tell which i have missed??

Comment: you don't need these permissions for executing shell commands. In your above code replace pm with adb

Comment: The adb also didn't work. Now the exit code for the process is 1.