# Install/uninstall an android application without user interaction in background

Tags: android

I am hitting web service and getting action to install and uninstall the application in background. Till now I am able to install and uninstall the application with user interaction.
I need that there should be no user interaction and the application should be installed / uninstalled as per the action in background without disturbing the user.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328471/can-we-do-silent-updation-for-android-application

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is not possible

Answer (score 0):

This kind of task can only be done by system apps, or apps with root access.

It is not possible via the public SDK for security reasons.